# How to modify line-spacing inside table environment?

Tags: tables, line-spacing

**Context** : I am using the table environment to make a table. I'm using `adjustbox` to control the width of my table. Here is what my code looks like :

```
   \begin{table}[htbp!]
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
        \begin{tabular}{|M{3.5cm}|M{3cm}|M{5cm}|M{4.5cm}|M{3cm}|}
            \hline
            \textsc{Loi} & \textsc{Paramètre(s)} & $\mathbb{P}(X = k)$ & \textsc{Moments} & $\vfi_X(t)$ \\[0.2cm]
            \hline
            \hline
            Uniforme $\mathcal{U}(E)$ & $E = (x_k)_{1 \lleq k \lleq n}$ & $\mathbb{P}(X = x_k) = \dfrac{1}{n}$ & $\mathbb{E}(X) = (n+1)(2n+1)/6$ $\text{Var}(X)=(n^2-1)/12$ & \\[0.3cm]
            \hline 
            Bernoulli $\mathcal{B}(p)$ & $p \in\ ]0,1[$ & $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=p$ $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1-p$ & $\mathbb{E}(X) = p$ $\text{Var}(X)=p(1-p)$ & $1-p+pe^{it}$ \\[0.3cm]
            \hline 
            Binomiale $\mathcal{B}(n,p)$ & $p \in\ ]0,1[$, $n \in \N^*$ & $\di\binom{k}{n}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, $0 \lleq k \lleq n$ & $\mathbb{E}(X) = np$ $\text{Var}(X)=np(1-p)$ & $\left(1-p+pe^{it}\right)^n$\\[0.3cm]
            \hline 
            Géométrique $\mathcal{G}(p)$ & $p \in\ ]0,1[$ & $p(1-p)^{k-1}$, $k \ggeq 1$ & $\mathbb{E}(X) = \dfrac{1}{p}$ $\text{Var}(X)=(1-p)/p^2$ & $\dfrac{pe^{it}}{1-(1-p)e^{it}}$\\[0.7cm]
            \hline 
            Poisson $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ & $\lambda > 0$ & $\dfrac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$, $k \ggeq 0$ & $\mathbb{E}(X) = \lambda$, $\text{Var}(X)=\lambda$ & $e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}$\\[0.1cm]
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Here $M$ is defined as follow : `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`. It allows me to have line changes when a text is too long inside a cell. It's kinda messy, but it works.

**My problem** : Line spacing inside my table is too small, making things hard to read. Here is an picture of what I get with the previous code :

[image: Cells in yellow are problematic]

Searching for some time didn't get me anywhere, as any promising answer had little to no effect to my table. Maybe the `setspace` package can be of some help, but nothing is working thus far and I can't find the documentation on CTAN.

I welcome every suggestion. Thanks for your time.

Comment: scaling tables with adjustbox or resizebox etc is evil, only use in a last resort (and even then avoid it if possible) it leads to inconsistent font sizes and rule widths, better to choose an appropriate font size such as `\small` or `\footnotesize` so that you can arrange a consistent typesetting.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not really an answer to your question, but I would not use `adjustwidth` that will squeeze the table with no control on the font size.

I removed the vertical rules that give no information and use simply `c` columns, with a trick for splitting some cells into two lines, generously spaced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{w{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\vfi}{\varphi}
\newcommand{\lleq}{\leqslant}
\newcommand{\ggeq}{\geqslant}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp!]

\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{Loi}}
& \textsc{Paramètre(s)}
& $\mathbb{P}(X = k)$
& \textsc{Moments}
& $\vfi_X(t)$
\\
\midrule
Uniforme $\mathcal{U}(E)$
& $E = (x_k)_{1 \lleq k \lleq n}$
& $\mathbb{P}(X = x_k) = \dfrac{1}{n}$
& \splitcell{$\mathbb{E}(X) = (n+1)(2n+1)/6$ \\ $\Var(X)=(n^2-1)/12$}
&
\\
\midrule
Bernoulli $\mathcal{B}(p)$
& $p \in \mathopen]0,1\mathclose[$
& \splitcell{$\mathbb{P}(X=1)=p$ \\ $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1-p$}
& \splitcell{$\mathbb{E}(X) = p$ \\ $\Var(X)=p(1-p)$}
& $1-p+pe^{it}$
\\
\midrule
Binomiale $\mathcal{B}(n,p)$
& \splitcell{$p \in \mathopen]0,1\mathclose[$, \\ $n \in \N^*$}
& \splitcell{$\binom{k}{n}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, \\ $0 \lleq k \lleq n$}
& \splitcell{$\mathbb{E}(X) = np$ \\ $\Var(X)=np(1-p)$}
& $(1-p+pe^{it})^n$
\\
\midrule
Géométrique $\mathcal{G}(p)$
& $p \in \mathopen]0,1\mathclose[$
& $p(1-p)^{k-1}$, $k \ggeq 1$
& \splitcell{$\mathbb{E}(X) = 1/p$ \\ $\Var(X)=(1-p)/p^2$}
& $\dfrac{pe^{it}}{1-(1-p)e^{it}}$
\\
\midrule
Poisson $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$
& $\lambda > 0$
& $\dfrac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$, $k \ggeq 0$
& \splitcell{$\mathbb{E}(X) = \lambda$, \\ $\Var(X)=\lambda$}
& $e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)}$
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Depending on your textwidth you might be able to use `\footnotesize` instead of `\scriptsize`.

Note the changes, namely `\Var` instead of the wrong `\text{Var}` and the typesetting of French-style open intervals.

[image]